# Can't update Google Sheets Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I've published an Add-on for Google Sheets to Google Web store.

Then I had to fix a small bug, but now I'm having troubles with publishing the updated version of script. When I click "Publish" in the Script Editor Menu, and then "Implement as Google Sheets Add-on" I see the following message:

[image: Box]

It is asking me to accept the terms and conditions of the store. After clicking review, I'm redirected to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/update?authuser=0 page, which is asking to upload a new zip file.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Here's a short video with the steps I'm following: [video](https://vimeo.com/133569102)

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue with updating the published add-on, you can submit your issue in the Chrome Web Store Support [page](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en) and provide all the details.

Comment: thanks, this has to be a bug, I've been around this for 24 hours now and it doesn't make sense to me. I need to push the update soon so if you have any other information, please let me know. Thanks!